# inverse search does not work for some paper

Tags: forward-inverse-search

I installed texstudio on a windows 8.1 computer. I first installed Miktex, then Texstudio, all are in the latest vision. It confused me that when I run some texfile, the inverse search function is fine. That is, when I right click at the pdf, then there is "go to the source", and it works. But for some texfile, when I right click at the pdf, there is no such  "go to the source". Does anyone knows the reason  behind this?

Answer (score 2):

This is a feature called `synctex`. The inverse search function relies on an auxillary file named `[jobname].synctex` (or `[jobname].synctex.gz`). If you delete this file, then you will unable to do an inverse search.

By default, TeXStudio will compile your document with the command line like

```
(pdf)latex -synctex=1 \jobname.tex
```

With the option `-synctex=1`, it will generate the file `[jobname].synctex.gz` for inverse search. However, if you compile the paper using command line directly, like

```
(pdf)latex \jobname.tex
```

Then no synctex file is created, so you can't do an inverse search.

More details can be found in `synctex.man1.pdf`, in your TeX distribution (MikTeX).

Comment: Then why does it work for some file not the others?

Comment: Have you ever deleted the synctex files unintentionally?

Comment: Thanks for your attention for my question. No, I did not delete the synctex file. Everytime I run the tex file, it would generate a synctex file. For some file, when i click left at the embedded pdf, there is the "go to source" option. But some tex file, no such option.  I found that the difference may come from the location of the latex file. The ones works are on the desktop, those do not work are in my D disk. So now when I want to edit some thing, I first put it to the desktop. This is not a good solution, But it seems that I have to go with it. Thanks again.